# Add an extra class to the Source value of Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I have an ExtJS RichText (CQ5 Component that has been extended from the `CQ.form.rte`).

There are rtePlugins that are supported using the following, as anyone would:

```
credit = new CQ.form.RichText({
    height       : 100,
    width        : 400,
    fieldLabel   : 'Photo Credit',
    rtePlugins   : {
        misctools: {
            features: ['specialchars', 'sourceedit'],
            specialCharsConfig: {
                chars: CN.Author.Util.specialCharacters
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I click on Source Edit, I want to manipulate the DOM and add a `class` to the HTML. What I mean is, I want the RTE editor to **automatically** add an extra class to the Source - the value of the RTE field, before saving. Kindly help

Comment: I don't want to go to ExtJS forums. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you'll have to probably override MiscToolsPlugins.js, EditorKernel.js, HtmlRules.js, and HtmlProcessor.js. Probably isn't worth it all. You are probably better off putting your rule in the styles drop-down (see [Styles](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html#Styles%20%28Text%29) plugin).

Comment: I have achieved it using the styles plugin. But this made an extra `span` to wrap my content, and then that `span` had the `class` I wanted. Not acceptable though but kind of worked.